# Understanding CGAffineTransform Rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have a `AVMutableComposition` which i'm applying transform to fix the orientations issue.

I solved all the others rotations cases, expect one.

```
else if (p.a == 0.0 && p.b == 1.0 && p.c == 1.0 && p.d == 0.0)
        {
            p.a = 1
            p.d = -1.0
            p.c = 0
            p.b = 0
            p.tx = 0
            p.ty = originalVideoTrack.naturalSize.width
        }
```

**The video is in the right size & shape. Tho he is missing 90 degrees rotations,in order to fit his layer. Any suggestions how can i achieve this 90 degrees rotate thru the matrix values?**

Answer (score 0):

you can just apply `preferedTransorm` property of AVAssetTrack to layer instruction

Comment: I'm aware to this options, Tho i'm using custom compositor(I'm applying filters etc'). In this case i need to create a new preferedTransorm